# Switching Sonarqube from embedded H2 to supported database

Tags: database, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I'm evaluating SQ 6.4 on RH Ent Linux using the H2 embedded DB.  This question [SonarQube backup restore procedure with ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340757/sonarqube-backup-restore-procedure-with-elasticsearch) indicates that to restore SQ from a backup of the RDBMS, one also needs to clear the Elasticsearch index, which SQ will subsequently rebuild to match the underlying DB.  I presume the same holds true if one wishes to switch from an eval version of SQ using the H2 database to some other, supported for production use database like Oracle?  Otherwise the new empty pristine RDBMS under the covers would be out of synch w/the ES document store, correct?

Apologies for asking a new Q instead of commenting/asking in the old thread - I don't have enough reputation pts to comment on threads yet :(

Comment: To be very sure you could also remove everything and start from scratch. Upgrade to SonarQube 6.7 while you are busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @jeroen-heier, you must clean up data/es directory when switching to another clean database.

And you should follow Jeroen's suggestion to use latest LTS version.